# Regex to remove a php function call

Tags: php, regex

i would like to remove some functions call from my php files. for example, how i can remove `mysql_escape_value` calls?
It's possible to have this situations:

```
<?php
mysql_escape_value ( "some" );    //-> "some"; or "some" ;
mysql_escape_value(some)         //-> some
.mysql_escape_value ($some ).    //-> .$some . or .$some.
. mysql_escape_value ($some ) .  //-> . $some  . or .$some . or .$some.
(mysql_escape_value ($some ))    //-> ($some)
( mysql_escape_value ($some ) )    //-> ($some ) or ( $some )
?>
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: to clean up a big project from deprecated functions

Comment: That's quite a mess if you use all of those variants

Comment: i just need that work, output doesn't matter

Comment: Would that be a problem if you just remove all mysql_escape_value calls? (that means that brackets would persist)

Comment: maybe after this operation is possible to run another regex to remove the double brackets?

Comment: If you write messy code, expect to have to clean up.

Comment: really? this is not my code and you are OT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try something of the like:

```
 *mysql_escape_value *\( *([^)]+?) *\)
```

And replace with `$1`

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/hE4aK7).